# Sample Cassandra database image for practice

Tags: cassandra

Is there any sample cassandra database image with data available which can be downloaded and restored in personal system/vm for practice purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such thing so I suspect it doesn't exist.

It should be easy enough to populate tables from free datasets on the internet in CSV format -- just do a search for any topic you're interested in.

Once you've got the data in CSV format, you can load it to Cassandra using the [DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html) tool. It allows you to bulk load data in CSV or JSON format to Cassandra. You can also use DSBulk to export data from Cassandra to CSV or JSON. It is open-source so it's free to use.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) has a free tier where you can launch a cluster in just 5 clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!